# How to fix Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:food_recipe/models/recipe.dart'?

Tags: flutter, dart, uri, usda-fooddata-central-api

I am using Android Studio as IDE. I get an error "Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:food_recipe/models/recipe.dart'" when I import the package.

I tried "flutter pub cache repair"folow by "flutter clean" , "flutter pub get" and "flutter package upgrade". I also closed and reopen my project. However, none of them are working.

Comment: Is `food_recipe` your app or a separate package?  If it's a separate package, does your `pubspec.yaml` list `food_recipe` as a dependency?  Does a `lib/models/recipe.dart` file exist in the `food_recipe` package?

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. It is a separate package, I needed to change the package name. It looks like the error has gone away.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.